# How does facebook/google/linkedin etc verifies SHA hash or app signing certificate

Tags: android, facebook, hash, sdk, certificate

All, faceboo/google/linkedin require you to generate a hash of your signing key and register it with them along with the bundle name of the application in order to let access login/profile etc.

If you try to use a different bundle name or different certificate for signing the application, they simply deny to serve the request.

My question is, how do they do it. How can I verify the hash of signing certificate used to sign the application in my API on the server end. I want to have a similar check for my application and I want to ensure that application signed with specific key only can access the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve APK signature info via [`PackageManager#getPackageInfo()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPackageInfo(java.lang.String,%20int)), compute a hash and pass it to your service to be compared to the value stored there previously when signing up.

That's also what the [Facebook SDK is doing](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/c7bb8d24843d34f49a7a696d246a8db7a76bd2c9/facebook/src/main/java/com/facebook/FacebookSdk.java#L636).

Comment: Of course it will not *ensure that application signed with specific key only can access the API.* ... as it is easy to get signature from any app and then mimic the API call to some webservice with this signature